# Push notification using rails web application

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, blackberry, rubygems, push-notification

Is there any gem or plugin which can be used to send push alerts on iphone, blackberry, and android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

[apns](https://github.com/jpoz/apns) = iOs

[c2dm](https://github.com/amro/c2dm) = Android

For Blackberry, you can use this discussion here, I haven't read it completely, just thought it might be helpful.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/push-notification-with-ruby-on-rails/td-p/598343

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/jwang/apn_on_rails) I used to work with this gem and it was OK Also dunno if it's compatible with rails 3

Comment: yes i also found it but i am unable to get token which is required to send notifications

Comment: you need an iPhone to get a token

Comment: Can't give you more info our iPhone app developer provided this info for me it maybe I'm missing sth but as far as I remember it was hexadecimal representation of a few bytes

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [jtv-apns](https://github.com/justintv/APNS)